# issue with form submitting in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Hey guy so I have this form I created that slides out and you can contact with it, located in the header.  For some reason if I submit it, it tells me page cannot be found - I made a page and gave it a template that sends the email.  If I just hit the submit button with no values it goes to the page with the thank you message.

Contact CODE:

```
<div id="feedback"><!-- Sliding contact form ---->

        <form method="post" action="../contactformsubmit">
            <h2>Phone: 847-782-9816</h2>
            <p><label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name"/></p>
            <p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email"/></p>
            <p><label>Subject: </label><input type="text" name="subject"/></p>
            <p><label>Message: </label><textarea name="message"></textarea></p>
            <p><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn"/></p>
        </form>
        <a href="#" class="pull_feedback" title="Click to leave feedback" ><img src=""/>Feedback</a>
</div>
<!-- end contact form -->
```

TEMPLATE CODE:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: formsubmit
*/
session_start();
get_header(); ?>
<style>
.item-post{
    margin: 0 0 1.625em;
    padding: 0 0 1.625em;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 365px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 2%;

}
.singular .item-post{
    text-align:center;  
}
.singular.page .hentry {
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    width: 17%;
    margin-top:1em;
    //height: 405px;

}
.singular.page .hentry:hover{
    background: #C9191B;
}
.singular .entry-title {
    font-size: 15px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}
.singular .entry-content {

    width:100%;

}
.singular .entry-header {

    width:100%;
    text-align:center;

}
.singular .discription {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding-left: 15%;
    height: 12%;
}
.singular .prodslideshow {
    display:none;   
}
.singular .pricing {
    padding-left: 15%;
}
</style>

        <div id="primary">

            <div id="content" role="main">
            <div class="thankyou" style="text-align:center; padding-top:1em; padding-bottom:1em;">
                    <h2>Thank you for contacting us!  We are here to make sure your time with us is a good one!  We will contact you as soon as we can.</h2>
                </div>
            <?php

            $message = $_POST['message'];
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];
            /*******SEND EMAIL**********/
                require_once "Mail.php";
                $body = "
Message from contact form!

$name
$email

$message
                ";
                // Send
                $from = "Contact Form ";
                //$to = "";
                $to = "";
                $host = "";
                $username = "";
                $password = "";

                $headers = array ('From' => $from,
                  'To' => $to,
                  'Subject' => $subject);
                $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
                  array ('host' => $host,
                    'auth' => true,
                    'username' => $username,
                    'password' => $password));

                $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);


            ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="../contactformsubmit">
```

You need to make sure the action URL is correctly pointing to your form. The current above one is looking to see if contactformsubmit is one directory above the contact form. It is likely in the same folder, so try:

```
<form method="post" action="contactformsubmit">
```

Also in case you meant to have an extension, I don't know your specific SEO setup, but this may also be what you meant:

```
<form method="post" action="contactformsubmit.php">
```

If these don't work please post the filepaths and full names of the contact form and contactformsubmit so we can setup the URL correctly.

Comment: I used ../contactformsubmit because in wordpress if your on a different page it will stack it...I do not need the .php because how wordpress formats it's pages.  the page is contactformsubmit and template is what it's wired to that sends out the email and that is a .php file but you ignore that because how wordpress works.

Comment: the url to page is `sitedir/contactformsubmit`

Comment: if sitedir is the root folder then do action="/sitedir/contactformsubmit"

Comment: If the problem was in the code you can answer your own question with the solution so that others who may have a similar issue can benefit from this post.

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to fix my problem with replacing the top form `<p><label>Name: </label><input type="text" name="name"/></p>`with `<p><label>Email: </label><input type="text" name="email"/></p>` and just changing values.  That's it :)  I think it was a spacing issue so that could be why.